# Does this phrase need to be wrapped in commas?

Tags: grammar, commas, sentence, syntactic-analysis

In the sentence below, does the phrase **"deep inside"** need commas wrapped around it?

> Moving has allowed me to view the incredible variety that the world has to offer, and it also has made me realize that, **deep inside**, humans have more in common with one another than one would initially think.

versus

> Moving has allowed me to view the incredible variety that the world has to offer, and it also has made me realize that **deep inside**, humans have more in common with one another than one would initially think.

versus

> Moving has allowed me to view the incredible variety that the world has to offer, and it also has made me realize that **deep inside** humans have more in common with one another than one would initially think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>That seems to me to be a standard nonrestrictive clause (meaning that it's not essential to the meaning of the sentence), and therefore needs commas around it.</strike> If you removed the commas, it would garble the syntax, because readers might expect something like

> ...realize that deep inside humans *lies something mysterious*...

If you really want to remove the commas, you could perhaps write

> ...realize that humans have more in common with one another deep inside than...

You also might remove just the first comma, but I'm not sure that's grammatical:

> ...realize that deep inside, humans have more in common...

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, I agree; it does "garble the syntax" without the commas. Seeing as there is no definitive rule, os this one of those subjective comma issues?

Comment: Commas in the wrong places can break a sentence into illogical segments or confuse readers with unnecessary and unexpected pauses.  The first comma is unnecessary and I much prefer @Rodney Atkins third example.. '...realize that deep inside, humans have more in common...'.

Comment: @sailorvenus, I believe it is subjective, but of course someone will judge you either way. :)

Comment: @GoodJuJu, I don't really buy into the "comma = pause" school of thought, but I see what you're saying.

Comment: In what way is 'deep inside' a clause? It's certainly a parenthetical. Offsetting punctuation is not mandatory for a parenthetical in every case, but here it would be inadvisable to leave it out because of the garden-path situation that, as you say, would result.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You have a point. It's more of a preposition, I guess.

Comment: It's a phrase. It lacks subject and finite verb, and never had them.

Comment: OK, I struck out the sentence. I think the answer is "useful" now.